# How to fetch data from a fake server in react native?

Tags: typescript, react-native, fetch

I have made a fake server in my laptop to fetch data. this is the data in it:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "Bill",
    "lastName": "Gates",
    "email": "bill@microsoft.com",
    "phone": "1234567898",
    "role": "Accountant",
    "org": "Organization 1"
  },
 {
    "id": 2,
   "firstName": "Mark",
   "lastName": "Zuckerberg",
   "email": "mark@facebook.com",
   "phone": "9876543212",
   "role": "Admin",
   "org": "Organization 1"
  }
]
```

I run the server using npm run mock:api

I want to fetch data from it and display in my physical android device(phone). This is my code I tried:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        users_fake: []
    }
}

componentDidMount() {

    fetch("https://192.168.43.164:4000/users")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((responseJson)=> {
        console.log('Response = ' + responseJson);
        this.setState({
            loading: false,
            users_fake: responseJson
        })
    })
    .catch(error=>console.log(error))
```

and this:

```
  fetch("http://localhost:4000/users")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((responseJson)=> {
        this.setState({
        loading: false,
        users_fake: responseJson
        })
        })
        .catch(error=>console.log(error))
```

and this:

```
 fetch('http://localhost:4000/users', {
            method: 'GET'
         })
         .then((response) => response.json())
         .then((responseJson) => {
            console.log(responseJson);
            this.setState({
               users_fake: responseJson
            })
         })
         .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
         });

}
```

I display data like this:

```
 { this.state.users_fake.map((user, index) => { 
     return (
         <Text>{user.firstName} {user.lastName}</Text>
     )
 })}
```

But I get error in console:

```
WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 16):
TypeError: Network request failed
```

What should I do to fetch data and display it?

Comment: Are you sure they are in the same network? To check you can open the link from browser of your phoen!

Answer (score 0):

Add throw error in catch function

```
fetch("https://192.168.43.164:4000/users")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((responseJson)=> {
        console.log('Response = ' + responseJson);
        this.setState({
            loading: false,
            users_fake: responseJson
        })
    })
    .catch(error=>{console.log(error);
throw error;})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It is showing error: ```Unexpected token, expected ","```

Comment: missed {} in catch function made changes to my answer check it.

Comment: The other thing is you are directly using loading in setState with out declaring it, check it once.

Comment: Have you tried the fetch with another api try this api "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"

Comment: I tried your code using the above api and its working perfectly i think there is a problem with your api, have you tried to get the data using postman